My hair cards vertex count range from 50k to 100k, would that be considered reasonable or sloppy?
I just can never make hair look smooth and realistic without winding up with excessive amounts of vertices. I'm intending to create hair for both games and animation, so I'm wondering if this excessive amount is reasonable?
Do you have any advice or links on creating realistic hair in a more structured and controlled way?
I'm also curious how you personally create hair and what is your average polycount range?
